# Kitten can't eat dry kibble

Tags: cats, eating

He's a 1 month old kitten. We used to feed him canned tuna and chicken. Yes, I know that isn't enough for him. Today we bought some dry kibble made for kittens, and put it in a bowl. He seems interested and tries to eat it, but the pieces either fall from his mouth or couldn't even chew them. I tried watering it a bit, but still couldn't chew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would feed wet until he's a bit older if he's having a hard time chewing. Those little teeth at 1 month can have a hard time, he will get better at it as he ages :).

4 weeks is the time when they begin to eat other things besides their mothers milk, learning process.

Comment: Thanks. I did think that he might have a problem with his teeth.

Comment: They are just very tiny and their jaws aren't as strong :) 5-6 weeks old and they're usually fine. They still seem like they're struggling but will end up crunching the bits with enough effort.

Comment: kittens get their first set of teeths from three weeks old and they are beeing replaced with their permanent teeths from 15 weeks old,so if you wait a couple of weeks the kitten will be ready for dry food.